# Create Amazon S3 Bucket on other organisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am attached to multiple organisations on Amazon, but I now need to create an S3 Bucket to Link it to an Alexa Skill on my clients account. I can't see anywhere that lets me switch organisations and create a Bucket on their account. I don't want to link my own and get billed for it.

Is it possible that you don't get billed for audio files that are used by Alexa Skills?

Comment: Does requester pays option help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html

Comment: No. This requires that whoever wants to pull down a file is authenticated. The Alexa/Polly API is the requester. I just want to create a Bucket on my clients account.